# how to combine two project on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to ask about the objective C on iPhone. I am writing a application, it contains 2 pages. The first page requires the user enter some information. The second page displays the tab page (3 tab).

And I create the first page and the second page in different project. I use the 'Window-based Application' to create the first one and use the 'Tab Bar Application' to create the second one.

However, I don't know how to combine it. Or should I build the second page in the first page project? If so,  what should I do and link the tab bar? As I don't know how to create a tab bar content in the first project.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The link below might help get you started, but you'll have some difficulty with the Tab Bar Controller part.  I usually create all those pieces programmatically...

http://pushplay.net/blog_detail.php?id=27

Comment: Thank you for your help. I also want to do this as programmatically. But I don't know how to do it as programmatically. Would you mind to give some link or example code to me? By the way, if i do it as programmatically, can I view the objective (e.g. view controller, view) in the .xib file? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does the "info page" collect some information and then not appear again under normal usage (e.g. a login screen)?  If so, I would recommend making the "tab page" your main view, and present the "info page" modally (with `presentModalViewController:animated:`).  It shouldn't be too hard to copy the view controller files and xib, if necessary, into the project with the "tab page".